# How to get current page from Navigation in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am new to Ionic2, and I am trying to build dynamic tabs based on current menu selection. I am just wondering how can I get current page using navigation controller.

```
...
export class TabsPage {
  constructor(navParams: NavParams,navCtrl:NavController) {
    //here I want to get current page
 }
}
...
```

From api documentation I feel `getActiveChildNav()` or `getActive()` will give me the current page, but I have no knowledge on `ViewController`/`Nav`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Full example:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class Page {

  constructor(public navCtrl:NavController) {
  }

  (...)

  getActivePage(): string {
    return this.navCtrl.getActive().name;
  }
}
```

Method to get current page name:

```
this.navCtrl.getActive().name
```

More details [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/)

Comment: this helped me a lot to prevent navCtrl to  go (and initialize all the stuff in it!) to a Page where we already are! Especially  in conjunction when subscribing to an observer multiple times, which ends up in an error!

Comment: [I don't think this method is recommended at all because production minify file names](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/viewcontroller-name/100497)

Comment: sir i tried but its not working in release build its return every time "l" in log can you help me this?

Answer (score 7):

OMG! This Really Helped mate, Tons of Thanks! @Deivide
I have been stuck for 1 Month, Your answer saved me. :)
Thanks!

```
if(navCtrl.getActive().component === DashboardPage){
    this.showAlert();
}
else
{
    this.navCtrl.pop();    
}
```

Comment: @Cozzbie it wasn't working for me either, turns out the value cant be accessed in the constructor. Only in functions executed after page load. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

My team had to build a separate custom shared menu bar, that would be shared and displayed with most pages. From inside of this menu component.ts calling `this.navCtrl.getActive().name` returns the previous page name. We were able to get the current page name in this case using:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 let currentPage = this.app.getActiveNav().getViews()[0].name;
 console.log('current page is: ', currentPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.navCtrl.getActive().name != TheComponent.name` 
or
`this.navCtrl.getActive().component !== TheComponent`

is also possible

Answer (score 0):

navCtrl.getActive() seems to be [buggy in certain circumstances](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/bug-navcontroller-getactive-doesnt-work-as-expected/108251/13), because it returns the wrong ViewController if .setRoot was just used or if .pop was just used, whereas navCtrl.getActive() seems to return the correct ViewController if .push was used.

Use the viewController emitted by the viewDidEnter Observable instead of using navCtrl.getActive() to get the correct active ViewController, like so:

```
navCtrl.viewDidEnter.subscribe(item=> {
          const viewController = item as ViewController;
          const n = viewController.name;
          console.log('active page: ' + n);
      });
```

I have tested this inside the viewDidEnter subscription, don't know about other lifecycle events ..

Comment: @Cleber Lopes de Albuquerque ' s answer works for .setRoot is this case.

Answer (score 0):

Old post. But this is how I get current page name both in dev and prod

```
this.appCtrl.getActiveNav().getActive().id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of**

```
...
...

//In debug mode alert value is 'HomePage'
//In production/ signed apk alert value is 'n'

alert(activeView.component.name);
if (activeView.component.name === 'HomePage') {
...
...
```

**Use this**

```
...
...

//In debug mode alert value is 'HomePage'
//In production/ signed apk alert value is 'HomePage'

alert(activeView.id);
if (activeView.id === 'HomePage') {
...
...
```

**[Source Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-lazy-loading-issue-get-current-component-page-view-name-in-production-release/)**

Answer (score -1):

You can use `getActive` to get active `ViewController`. The `ViewController` has `component` and its the instance of current view. The issue is the comparsion method. I've came up to solution with settings some field like `id:string` for all my Page components and then compare them. Unfortunately simple checking function name so `getActive().component.name` will break after minification.

Comment: You're right, and if you use the component comparison `getActive().component === ComponentName`? It worked for me.

Comment: But it wont work after code minification as the namings will be changed.

Comment: This method compares the component itself rather than its name. As if we were to compare the following:

```x = y = function () {}; x === y;```

Do you understand?

Comment: Yep. Maybe im wrong but such approach breaks for me after minification. I'll try it again in a free time and check.