# this.viewCtrl.name always give result 't' in --prod mode

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hello friends I am using ionic 2 'ViewController'

I have to print Current active page.

I am using ViewController to print current active Page .

```
console.log(this.viewCtrl.name);
```

also use

//returns view controller obj

```
let view = this.nav.getActive();
```

//prints out component name as string

```
console.log(view.component.name);
```

This code I am using but every page I found result **'t'**.

I am used lots of way but its still gives same result.

I refer - [How to get current page from Navigation in ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747921/how-to-get-current-page-from-navigation-in-ionic-2)

**And**

[How to get current page name?](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-current-page-name/52993)

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Looks like you are getting this in `prod mode`?

Comment: yes , I am using prod mode while building app.